# H12 Heroku error when making POST request with Axios and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, netlify

I've made a React.JS app, which I've hosted on Netlify, which sends POST requests to a Node.JS server hosted on Heroku. Whenever I send a POST request, it works temporarily, but 30 seconds later it sends an H12 error. I've tried everything but nothing has seemed to work. The link to my client is [here](https://github.com/bobobo34/word-data-react-app). My server code is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require("./config/db");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = 3001;
const timeout = require('connect-timeout');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://coruscating-dolphin-7548e8.netlify.app");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.post('/api/test', timeout('2s', {respond: false}), cors(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("test");
    console.log(req.body.test);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, () => {
    console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp12D.png) is the error I keep getting in the browser.

And here it is in Heroku:

```
2022-04-24T23:02:29.132724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/test" host=word-data-database.herokuapp.com request_id=2c39695c-e8ec-47c2-9940-e85ec3ccd450 fwd="65.189.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Note: I had POSTs and GETs that used my database, but I cut them out to test if they were the problem, they weren't.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) You have a CORS issue so you'll need to resolve that (there are plenty of posts on here how to do that). 2) The other thing is that if you're using a free Heroku dyno it may just be shutting down because its inactive which might also be causing you problems.

Comment: I'm stupid; the solution was to add res.send...